# How to export image from material

Tags: texturing, export, add-on

I have install Blender texture tool from [here](https://github.com/amb/blender-texture-tools/)

[Video how Addon works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxYBPbBG_Cg)

What this addon do in the UV image Editor when click on Generated it Generates Normal, Specular and Diffuse images automatically.

I want to export those 3 images to my PC folder which are generated from this addon we can see in the material list.

I can select that texture and save as in uv but i want to save all 3. If i have more texture how then

Reason why i need this 3 file with the Node Wrangler addon. With the Principle Base node selected Press Ctrl+Shift+T you have to access this 3 images (Normal, Specular and Diffuse) from the PC folder.

[image]

So any suggestion or help how can i export or get this 3 images generated from the addon

Comment: Use "save as image" (F3)

Comment: @cegaton yeah i have mention above i can save each image by selecting but i want to export or save all of them at one time. How is that possible